# INSERT OR IGNORE seems to update non unique fields

Tags: javascript, sqlite, cordova, cordova-plugins

I am using SQLite for an app.
On device ready I want to add a database and create + fill a table with some data using the Sqlite cordova plugin.
When the database already exists it doesn't have to add and fill it.

So I came with this code:

```
onDeviceReady: function() {

    //create the SQLite database
    APP.db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({name: 'my.db', iosDatabaseLocation: 'default', androidLockWorkaround: 1}, HKV.successDB, HKV.errorDB);

    if (APP.showDemo === true) {
        APP.db.transaction(APP.queryDB, APP.errorDB);
    }

},

 successDB: function () {

    //fill database
    APP.db.sqlBatch([
        'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS demo (id unique, version)',
        'INSERT OR IGNORE INTO demo (id, version) VALUES (1, null)',
        'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS instaDemo (id unique, show)',
        'INSERT OR IGNORE INTO instaDemo (id, show) VALUES (1, "true")'
    ], function (success) {
        //
    }, function (error) {
        alert('DB2 Error: ' + error.message);
    });

},
```

The very first time starting the app this does work.
After the first run the 'null' at the version column will be changed.
I tested this and the value does change. So this is not! the issue.

The next time I start the app I would expect the 'demo' table to have an id (from the first run) and would ignore the INSERT statement.

However it seems it does set the version value to null leaving the id for what it is. This is behaviour I do not expect. This way it would be like an INSERT OR UPDATE statement.

Is this normal behaviour?
And if so: What can I do to prevent this from happening?

I also tried in different variaties:

```
INSERT OR ABORT
```

Comment: Why do you expect the version value to be something other than null?

Comment: Ah good one! Later in the script I change this to the real version of the app.

Comment: The evidence indicates that this does not happen. Why do you think the problem is with the INSERT?

Comment: Nope not the evidence, the assumption, I checked this and it does change, will check this again. Though I did see this change.

Comment: You need to show a [mcve].

Comment: I could say something now, but lets leave it at that this is not easy to do with cordova. I checked it again and it does change, so what else could it be?